# how to search files using php (need alternative way for linux find)

Tags: php, file, search, find

I need to execute following linux find command

```
find /home/*/mail/ -type d -name ".test" > tmp_file
```

but using php (since the find command for some reason freeze in some OS) .
How to do this search using php and put results in tmp_file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `FilesystemIterator`, `DirectoryIterator`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use glob function.

Check it out http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php